# Why Entry on Xamarin.Forms on Windows shows empty even if it contains text until I click it?

Tags: text, xamarin.forms, uwp

I create an Entry on Xamarin.Forms using the following code

```
Entry txtMeasures = new Entry { WidthRequest = 100, Text = "32", TextColor = Color.Black };
```

The text that should appear is "32" but the entry appears empty on UWP app until I click the entry,
this happen only on Windows, on Mac, Android, iOs, the entry shows the text normally since it appears.

Entry Before Clicking

[image: y]

Entry After Clicking

[image]

Comment: put Placeholder and check for that, Placeholder text is coming or not in UWP

Comment: The issue is with the placeholder color!!!

Comment: txtMeasures.Placeholder = "32";
txtMeasures.PlaceholderColor = Color.Black;
This works only if I set the text empty txtMeasures.Text = "", but this is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

I add Entry by code behind, but I don't have any issue in Android and UWP.

Firstly, set current cpntentpage stacklayout name as stacklayout1.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout1">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Then add Entry in Stacklayout.

```
 Entry txtMeasures = new Entry { WidthRequest = 100, Text = "32", TextColor = Color.Black };
        stacklayout1.Children.Add(txtMeasures);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue with Entries on UWP:

[Text is not visible on Entry element after animation finished #8503](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8503)

[Entry text initially invisible on UWP #8787](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8787)

[Fix 8503, 8787 - text in Entry not immediately visible, or visible after IsVisible set to true #8536](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/8536)

There are a couple of work arounds (set request height on the entry or where its wrapped in a scrollview have that wrap a ContentPresenter).  I'm having this issue related to a scrollView but can't get either workaround to work ‍♂️